# How to code with JCIP (Java Concurrency in Practice)

Tags: java, concurrency

Recently read up on JCIP annotations and they seem cool. Went to the website and took a look at the source. The only problem is that the src jar just contains the annotations...I'm not seeing where I can find the annotation processors that actually *do* anything! Am I just looking in the wrong place, or are these not real Java annotations (meaning, is there no way to enforce `@Immutable` when it is used to mark a class)?

- `@Immutable`
- `@GuardedBy`

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what JCIP is.  I assume you mean Java Concurrency in Practice but it should be expanded.  And I'm not familiar with which annotations you mean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) supports those annotations. The support for those annotations and others is described in [this documentation page](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html).

Comment: So the JCIP annotations - whats the point of them? Are they just "hollow" annotations used in the JCIP examples to help the readers follow along, or is there some kind of alliance between JCIP and FindBugs?

Comment: Annotations in general are just that: annotations. They annotate your source and/or byte code. All the annotations (unless they're used purely for documentation purpose) are supposed to be handled by some tool. In the case of JCIP annotations, FindBugs is such a tool. If you annotate some class as immutable, and the class is in fact not immutable, FindBugs will generate a warning when inspecting this class. JCIP annotations have two purposes: they document the design of the code, and they can be usd by FindBugs and other tools to check that the intended design is respected.

Answer (score 4):

The IntelliJ IDE will use these annotations to look for bugs in your code. If you annotate a variable is @GuardedBy(some_lock), the IDE will flag cases where you access it without properly synchronizing on it. This is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The JCIP annotations are a formal way to document a concurrency contract such as this member is "@GuardedBy" this field.

They don't do anything functionally in your code.